# django orm layer

Tags: php, sql, django, django-orm

I have two tables, `subscriptions` and `user_subscription`. I wanted to be able to search from the `name` field in `subscription` for anything the user is not already subscribed to. I wrote a sql query as per below:

```
select e.*
from subscription e, user_subscription u
where e.id != u.sub_id and u.user_id = 7 and e.name like '%mic%'
order by name limit 0,50
```

My question is, is there a way to do this query using the django orm framework? I'm able to do the search of `subscription` table properly, problem is that when the user is already subscribed, I don't want those results to show. The `sub_id` field in `user_subscription` is a foreign key relationship mapping to the `subsciption` id.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant parts of your models file? I'd have an easier time understanding how the relationships work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - look into the [Manager.raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw) method, which will let you run raw SQL queries. You'd want to use `Subscription.objects.raw(...)` for your query.

Comment: Yeah..right now i'm using raw sql query already. I was hoping there was a way to do it within the framework, oh well.